# Ms Excel 2016 VBA how to use .top and .left

Tags: excel, vba

I have EXCEL 2016 English
I am using the following code:

```
Sub PastePicture(Direccion)
Dim Altura As Long
Dim Width As Long
    ActiveSheet.Range(Direccion).Select

    Height = RangeHeight(Direccion) - 3
    Width = RangeWidth(Direccion) - 4

    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.Top = rCell.Top + 3   ' this is not working
    Selection.Left = rCell.Left + 2 ' this is not working
    Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    Selection.Width = Width
    Selection.Height = Height
End Sub
```

`Direccion` is a Range of cells.
`Rangeheight` and `RangeWidth` are two functions calculating the size of the range.
I would like to paste the picture to the range but defining the `.Top` and `.Left`.
So positioning not exactly in the corner of the range, but a little bit on the inside.
I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Where does `rCell` come from?

Comment: What error are you getting when it doesn't work?

Comment: "Direccion is a Range of cells" would go without saying if the procedure's signature said `Public Sub PastePicture(ByVal Direccion As Range)` ;-)

Comment: If `Direccion` really is a `Range`, then if it's not on the `ActiveSheet` your code will blow up on the first executable statement there. Either do `Direccion.Select`, or reconsider whether you need to `.Select` anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these funtions, ShapePosition should do the job if you use it in your code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim cShp As Shape
    Dim cRng As Range

    Set cRng = Range("B3:F12")
    Set cShp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1) 'Takes the selected picture

    Call ShapePosition(cShp, cRng, 50, 50) 'The picture is getting centered

End Sub


Sub ShapePosition(xShp As Shape, xRng As Range, xOffsetTop As Double, xOffsetLeft As Double)

' If xOffseTop is 0 - the picture is fully to the top of the range, when 50 - it is centered, 100 - fully to the bottom
' If xOffseLeft is 0 - the picture is fully to the left of the range, when 50 - it is centered, 100 - fully to the right

    If xShp.Height > xRng.Height Or xShp.Width > xRng.Width Then
        MsgBox "The picture is too big!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    xShp.Top = xRng.Top + ((xRng.Height - xShp.Height) * xOffsetTop / 100)
    xShp.Left = xRng.Left + ((xRng.Width - xShp.Width) * xOffsetLeft / 100)

End Sub
```